# Print Customize record in crystal report

Tags: ms-access, crystal-reports-xi

i would like to customize Crystal report
Example
i have 20 records and i would like to print 4 record in one page but record sequence is per page as below

[image]

Comment: For Access report solution that might be able to adapt, review https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=73256

Comment: Why is there a number 6 at end of 5th group?